# invalid-input-response google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha-v3

i got the error `stdClass Object ( [success] => [error-codes] => Array ( [0] => invalid-input-response ) )`
when i implement invisible google recapture , however the site key and the secret key provided are valid here's is the full code ..

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6Lf_wNwlAAAAAFNZFttJLg6ii2KMsPvquGTEi1fh"></script>
```

php code

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $url ='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $secret = '6Lf_wNwlAAAAAJ7eikDFSiBSD0vfuA5XFvcnEjou';
    $response = $_POST['ge-recaptcha'];
    $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $request = file_get_contents($url . '?secret=' . $secret. '&response=' . $response . '&remoteip=' . $remoteip);
    $result=json_decode($request);
    print_r($result);
    if($result->success == true){
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("data saved successfully");
        </script>
        <?php
    }else{
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("data not saved");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

html code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
        <div id="alert_message"></div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
           </div>
<input type="hidden" name="ge-recaptcha" value="" id="recaptchaResponse">
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="padding: 6px 46px; margin: 16px 0 0 0;">
        </form>
     </div>
```

javascript code

```
 <script>
    document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      function validateForm() {
          let isValid = true;
        const emailInput = document.querySelector('#email');
        if (emailInput.value.trim() === '') {
          alert('Please enter an email address');
          return false;
        }
        return isValid
      }
    
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('6Lf_wNwlAAAAAFNZFttJLg6ii2KMsPvquGTEi1fh', { action: 'submit' }).then(function(token) {
          let response = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
          response.value = token;
        });
      });
    
      if (!validateForm()) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
         </script>
```

why does this error appear ? any help to fix the error will be appreciated

Comment: I hope that's your not your _real_ recaptcha secret key which you've just shared with the whole world? If it is, I suggest you go and change it in your recaptcha config right now.

Comment: @ADyson what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Did you understand my comment? You should not expose your secret key on this website

Comment: Anyway, in terms of your code, it looks like you are sending the parameters to the /verify endpoint in the querystring. According to the documentation and the various examples online, they are supposed to be in the body of the request. See the duplicate question (in the blue box above) for more info and examples.